# how to get value by click event in angular 6 into component file

Tags: components, angular6

I want to pass selected item in list by selectQueries function to the componenet file but i m facing error like outlook is not a function on the console.

HTML File:-

```
  <li>
    <a href="#" style="width:auto"  (click)="selectQueries(bottomBar.outlook) ">{{'bottomBar.outlook' | translate}}</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" (click)="selectQueries(bottomBar.oneDrive)">{{'bottomBar.oneDrive' | translate}}</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" (click)="selectQueries(bottomBar.restartingPC)">{{'bottomBar.restartingPC' | translate}}</a>
  </li>
```

Component.ts file

```
selectQueries(query: string) {   
this.translate.use(query);  
this.currentQuery = query; 
console.log('here',this.currentQuery);
```

}

but here i m getting undefined response.

bottombar data present on bt.json:-

```
 "bottomBar":{
    "outlook": "Invites keep getting deleted in Outlook",
    "oneDrive": "Access to OneDrive",
    "restartingPC":"My PC keeps restarting"        
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to put async & await -

```
async selectQueries(query: string) {   
   await this.translate.use(query);  
   await this.currentQuery = query; 
   console.log('here',this.currentQuery);
}
```

Comment: can you edit your post and copy the related syntax on ts file?